# Getting rid of the red squiggly underline on errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a lot of trouble reading my own code when there is an error because of this red squiggly line:

[image: red squiggly in return value]

It's especially annoying when you code with expressions rather than statements because it underlines the whole thing.

I couldn't find a setting that controls its appearance. I would rather have the background change colour, as I have it set up with Error Lens, or simply customise the underline color to make it really really faint.

I don't know how much time I waste refactoring to single out parts of the code so I can read it, or worse, finding a missing closing braket...

Comment: idk VSCode but presumably it's trying to help you fix areas that will not compile due to syntax errors.

Comment: If you want to customize their color, check out [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610661/1025421). // They are displayed for a reason: The code is wrong. I do not frequently encounter them while working.

Comment: My hero! I encounter them all the freaking time! Try refactoring anything that is an expression without breaking some type, syntactic rule or function name. As soon as you type you can't read what you are typing any more.

Comment: that code looks like a typescript arrow function that states the return value is a `number` yet you return a `string` - perhaps if you wrote valid code VScode wouldn't complain that your code is invalid

Comment: Oh gee, I thought that every string that starts with `jl kjlkjlkjlkjkj` was actually of type `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Daniel in the comments.

I ended up adding this to my user `settings.json` to kill the underline and replace it with a background color ("Eva Dark" is the theme I wanted to target):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "[Eva Dark]": {
      "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
      "editorError.background": "#ff757522",
   }
}
```

To access it: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`, then start typing `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`

That's muuuuuch more readable
[image]